# VirtualBox application error - memory could not be written

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I'm trying to spin up a virtual box machine (ver 5.0.8 ) using vagrant set up.Whenever vagrant is trying to spin up virtualbox machine , the VirtualBox runs into an application error of referenced memory , stating memory could not be written.

[image]

Post this vagrant goes into aborted state and exits out mentioning the below -

```
"==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
 ==> default: Booting VM...
 ==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
     The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it
     to boot. Valid states are 'starting, running'. The machine is in the
     'aborted' state. Please verify everything is configured
     properly and try again.

     If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it,
     it is often helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the
     GUI often has more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
     For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
     VirtualBox GUI is open.

     The primary issue for this error is that the provider you're using
     is not properly configured. This is very rarely a Vagrant issue."
```

Attached snapshot of the error seen on VirtualBox .

Could you please help giving some pointers to what could be done to fix this ?

Vbox.log below -

```
VirtualBox VM 5.0.8 r103449 win.amd64 (Oct 15 2015 14:48:29) release log
00:00:01.410339 Log opened 2015-11-10T15:59:54.878373900Z
00:00:01.410340 Build Type: release
00:00:01.410343 OS Product: Windows 7
00:00:01.410344 OS Release: 6.1.7601
00:00:01.410345 OS Service Pack: 1
00:00:01.509169 DMI Product Name: 20BWS04K03
00:00:01.511022 DMI Product Version: ThinkPad T450s
00:00:01.511030 Host RAM: 11984MB total, 7547MB available
00:00:01.511032 Executable: C:\ProgramFiles\Oracle\VirtualBox\VirtualBox.exe
00:00:01.511032 Process ID: 11168
00:00:01.511033 Package type: WINDOWS_64BITS_GENERIC
00:00:01.512131 Installed Extension Packs:
00:00:01.512291   None installed!
00:00:01.518132 Console: Machine state changed to 'Restoring'
00:00:01.519779 GUI: UIMediumEnumerator: Medium-enumeration finished! 
00:00:01.524933 Console: Machine state changed to 'Saved'
00:00:01.560185 Power up failed (vrc=VINF_SUCCESS, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
00:00:01.880946 GUI: UIMachineViewNormal::adjustGuestScreenSize: Adjust guest-screen size if necessary.
```

Comment: can you create simple VM using Virtual Box (without vagrant) - I think this has not much  to do with vagrant in your case, maybe uninstall / reinstall VirtualBox

Comment: Not able to create that as well , same error.I tried importing a disk file .vmdk , creating a disk file options but they shoot up same error.I've uninstalled and re-installed the VirtualBox machine but that doesn't solve the issue.Is this something to do with some configuration done by VM machine on  windows files which needs to be fixed ?

Comment: you should post your VirtualBox.log file to get more info about the root cause of the crash. usually this is 3D acceleration (try disabling) or some unsigned driver that causes this issue

Comment: added log in the edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was with Oracle VM box 5.0.8 working in conjunction with Vagrant 1.7.I downgraded to Oracle VM box ver 4.3.12 and this problem was fixed